# $f=x^6+6x+6 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, what is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question is:

> Consider $f=x^6+6x+6 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, what is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$?

As far as I can see, $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ is a field, because $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain and $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, thus $(f)$ is a maximal ideal.
Now I think I need one of the roots of the polynomial (or all of them) to get a basis over $\mathbb{Q}$. But it seems to be hard to find them. The polynomial looks somehow like a cyclotomic polynomial. How can I get its roots easily? Is it possible to work with the derivative somehow?
I can also see, that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ must be a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $6$, because $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, therefore I should get a basis knowing the roots, I guess.

Comment: A root of $x^6+6x+6$ in $\mathbb{Q}[t]/(f(t))$ is $t+(f)$. A $\mathbb(Q)$-basis can be $1,t,t^2,...,t^5$ (all $+(f)$).

Comment: A basis is $\mathcal B=\left\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\right\}\,.$

Comment: I would say that one such basis is$$\{1+(f(x)),x+(f(x)),x^2+(f(x)),x^3+(f(x)),x^4+(f(x)),x^5+(f(x))\}.$$